# Nested attribute values set during build not being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I am trying to build some nested objects with specific attribute values. A listing `has_many` orders, and an order `has_many` order_events.

Ideally, when a new listing is created and saved, the associated order (with the seller_id set) and the order_event (with the state set) should be created and saved as well.

I am running into two problems:

1. The order is saved, but the seller_id is not.
2. The order_event is not saved at all.

In the controller, I have:

```
def new                                                                                                                                                            
  @listing = Listing.new

  @order = @listing.orders.build(seller_id: current_user.id)

  @order_event = @listing.orders.first.order_events.build(state: 'confirmed')
end

def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to manage_path, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else    
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def listing_params
  params.require(:listing).permit(:title, :address, :size, :min_lease, :price, :description, :state, space_ids: [], amenity_ids: [], images_files: [], images_attributes: [:id, :_destroy], orders_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :start, :end, :seller_id, order_events_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :state]])
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you adding the fields to your form in the view for the order and order event? When the form is submitted those attributes are lost and "rebuilt" during the create action.

Comment: No, I initially set the values using `hidden_fields` in the form, but I removed those from the form and moved the logic to the controller.

Comment: in that case you should move the two assigns to your create action before saving the listing. That way they are included in the same instance of Listing

Comment: Just to clarify, I had some `hidden_fields` that were responsible for setting the attribute values, but I do include fields for selecting order start and end dates.

I just want to set specific attribute values for the nested objects without using `hidden_fields`.

Comment: The attributes you want to assign, but not include in your view, will need to be assigned in the create action. The new and create actions are working with two different instances of Listing and are being lost between requests. I'll post an answer in more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The trouble is that I need:

   @order = @listing.orders.build(seller_id: current_user.id)

in the new action in order to create the order start and end date fields in the form. I was just hoping to assign a default value to those in the new action. I guess that I can just assign the value after the fact in the create action.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure if you need the seller_id in the view, but if you do then you may want to move the order and order event builds into a method that is called in the new and create actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your create action try assigning `seller_id` and `@order_event` like so.

```
def new                                                                                                                                                            
  @listing = Listing.new

  @order = @listing.orders.build
  @order_event = @order.order_events.build
end

def create
  @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

  @order = @listing.orders.first
  @order.seller_id = current_user.id

  @order_event = @order.order_events.build(state: 'confirmed')

  respond_to do |format|
    if @listing.save
      format.html { redirect_to manage_path, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
    else    
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It works, but I did have to add `if @order.present?` since I have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, reject_if: lambda { |a| a[:start].blank? || a[:end].blank? }, allow_destroy: true` in my model. Overall, everything works.

Comment: Could catch, I didn't think of that.